# Перегрузка операторов ввода/вывода для файлов

Tags: c++, ооп

Помогите, пожалуйста, с перегрузкой ввода/вывода для файлов. Выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> Ошибка C2678; бинарный ">>": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "std::ifstream" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Вот, собственно, сам код:

````
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class immovables
{
private:
    string name; // найменування
    float price; // ціна
    size_t area; // розмір
    string address; // адреса
    string facilities; // зручності
    string repair; // ремонт
    long int phone_num; // номер телефону
public:
    void print_inf();
    void input();
    void price_increase();
    bool conditions();
    string get_name();

    immovables();
    immovables(string name, float price, size_t area, string address, string facilities, string repair, long int phone_num);
    immovables(const immovables& imm);
    ~immovables() {};

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const immovables& imvb);
    friend ofstream& operator<< (ofstream& ofs, const immovables& imvb);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, immovables& imvb);
    friend ifstream& operator>> (ifstream& ifs, const immovables& imvb);
};

void immovables::print_inf()
{
    cout << *this;
}

void immovables::input()
{
    cin >> *this;
}

void immovables::price_increase()
{
    price = price * 2;
}

bool immovables::conditions()
{
    if (area > 100)
    {
        string str("Ленінський");
        size_t found = address.find(str);

        if (found != std::string::npos)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else return 0;
    }
    else return 0;
}

string immovables::get_name()
{
    return name;
}

immovables::immovables()
{
    name = "";
    price = 0;
    area = 0;
    address = "";
    facilities = "";
    repair = "";
    phone_num = 0;
}

immovables::immovables(string name, float price, size_t area, string address, string facilities, string repair, long int phone_num)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->price = price;
    this->area = area;
    this->address = address;
    this->facilities = facilities;
    this->repair = repair;
    this->phone_num = phone_num;
    assert(price > 0 && phone_num > 380000000000 && phone_num < 380100000000);
}

immovables::immovables(const immovables& imm)
{
    name = imm.name;
    price = imm.price;
    area = imm.area;
    address = imm.address;
    facilities = imm.facilities;
    repair = imm.repair;
    phone_num = imm.phone_num;
}

ofstream& operator<< (ofstream& ofs, const immovables& imvb)
{
    ofs << imvb;

    return ofs;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const immovables& imvb)
{
    out << "Найменування: " << imvb.name << "; Ціна: " << imvb.price << "; Розмір (у м^2): " << imvb.area << "; Адреса: " << imvb.address << "; Зручності: " << imvb.facilities << "; Ремонт: " << imvb.repair << "; Номер телефону:" << imvb.phone_num << endl;

    return out;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& in, immovables& imvb)
{
    cout << " Введіть найменування нерухомості: ";
    in >> imvb.name;
    cout << " Введіть ціну: ";
    in >> imvb.price;
    cout << " Введіть розмір (у м^2): ";
    in >> imvb.area;
    cout << " Введіть адрес: ";
    in >> imvb.address;
    cout << " Введіть наявні зручності та переваги: ";
    in >> imvb.facilities;
    cout << " Введіть стан нерухмості: ";
    in >> imvb.repair;
    cout << " Введіть номер телефону власників: ";
    in >> imvb.phone_num;

    return in;
}

ifstream& operator>> (ifstream& ifs, const immovables& imvb)
{
    ifs >> imvb.name >> imvb.price >> imvb.area >> imvb.address >> imvb.facilities >> imvb.repair >> imvb.phone_num;

    return ifs;
}


class show
{
public:
    immovables* getImm();
    void print_inf(int N);
    void input(int N);
    void price_increase(int N);
    void conditions(int N);
    void delete_found(int N);
    immovables* del_element(immovables* arr, int len, short num);

    show();
    show(immovables* imm, string client_fname, string agent_fname, string date_show, string result);
    show(const show& sh);
    ~show();

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const show& sh);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, show& sh);
private:
    immovables* imm;

    string client_fname;
    string agent_fname;
    string date_show;
    string result;
};

immovables* show::getImm()
{
    return imm;
}

void show::print_inf(int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        imm[i].print_inf();
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << *this << endl;
}

void show::input(int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        imm[i].input();
    }
    cout << endl;

    cin >> *this;
}

void show::price_increase(int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (imm[i].get_name() == "Квартира")
        {
            imm[i].price_increase();
        }
        else continue;
    }
}

void show::conditions(int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (imm[i].conditions())
        {
            cout << imm[i] << endl;
        }
        else cout << " Такої квартири не знайдено." << endl;
    }
}

/*void show::delete_found(int N)
{
    int choice;
    cout << " Оберіть критерій, за яким бажаєте видалити запис (1 - найменування, 2 - ціна, 3 - розмір, 4 - адреса, 5 - зручності, 6 - ремонт, 7 - номер телефону)." << endl;
    cout << " Ваш вибір => ";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        string str;
        cout << " Введіть найменування: ";
        cin >> str;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (imm[i].get_name() == str)
                del_element(imm, N, i);
        }
        break;
    }
}*/

immovables* show::del_element(immovables* arr, int len, short num)
{
    if (num <= len && num >= 1)
    {
        --num;
        immovables* tmp = new immovables[len - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) tmp[i] = arr[i];
        for (int i = num; i < len - 1; ++i) tmp[i] = arr[i + 1];
        delete[] arr;
        arr = tmp;
        --len;
        return arr;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error\n";
        return arr;
    }
}

show::show()
{
    client_fname = "";
    agent_fname = "";
    date_show = "";
    result = "";
}

show::show(immovables* imm, string client_fname = "", string agent_fname = "", string date_show = "", string result = "")
{
    this->imm = imm;
    this->client_fname = client_fname;
    this->agent_fname = agent_fname;
    this->date_show = date_show;
    this->result = result;
}

show::show(const show& sh)
{
    imm = sh.imm;
    client_fname = sh.client_fname;
    agent_fname = sh.agent_fname;
    date_show = sh.date_show;
    result = sh.result;
}

show::~show()
{
    delete[] imm;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const show& sh)
{
    out << " ПІБ клієнта: " << sh.client_fname << "; ПІБ агента: " << sh.agent_fname << "; Дата показу: " << sh.date_show << "; Результат: " << sh.result << "." << endl;

    return out;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& in, show& sh)
{
    cout << " Введіть ФІО клієнта: ";
    in >> sh.client_fname;
    cout << " Введіть ФІО агента з продажу: ";
    in >> sh.agent_fname;
    cout << " Введіть дату показу: ";
    in >> sh.date_show;
    cout << " Введіть результат показу: ";
    in >> sh.result;

    return in;
}```
````

Comment: уберите константность аргумента, куда вы хотите что-то записать при чтении. `ifstream& operator>> (ifstream& ifs,` **const** `immovables& imvb)`

Comment: Увидел, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с файловыми потоками нужно добавить `<fstream>`. И убрать нужно константность в аргументе куда вы хотите что-то записать.

```
# include <fstream>

ifstream& operator>> (ifstream& ifs, /* const */ immovables& imvb);
```

Comment: Вы мне можете, пожалуйста, подсказать с удалением элементов из динамического массива?

Comment: Чтобы не забывать, что указатель изменился, передавайте ссылкой на этот указатель. `void show::del_element(immovables* & arr, int len, short num)`